# upstart: mail error report on segfault

Tags: upstart

I have a process that's managed by upstart.   It sends an error report on internal exceptions, but since the app isn't written in C, it cannot catch a SIGSEGV and send an error report on that.   (Not that that would be a good practice in C either).

I would think that it should be possible to have upstart kick off a script to send the error report, but I can't figure out how to do this.   There seem to be three possible approaches:

1) a post-stop script.   However, EXIT_SIGNAL is not available in a post-stop script

2) `start on stopped`.  Create a separate upstart config with a `start on stopped` script.  This works great, but only if I remove `respawn` from the original config.   That's not acceptable.

3) Use scripting techniques:

```
script
  cmd &
  PID=$!
  wait $PID
  if [ $? = 139 ] ; then cleanup ; fi
end script
```

However, the upstart script block appears to work like `set -e` in a shell, so the script exits when cmd fails, and we never get to the if block.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work.   The trick is similar to #3, but use a shell script in a file rather than inline in the upstart.conf.  That way you can skip the `-e` and you can use bash rather than dash.

If you really want to avoid a separate script, you can bypass the `-e` behaviour by using `||`:

```
script
  cmd &
  PID=$!
  wait $PID || export EXIT_CODE=$?
  if [ $EXIT_CODE -eq 139 ] ; then cleanup ; fi
end script
```